# PHP File Upload with Dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, apache, dropzone

I've got a PHP app that uses the Dropzone upload control. Currently `JPEG/JPG` file types work and get uploaded and processed correctly (i.e. moved to an `uploads` folder) but `PNG` silently fails and I can't figure out why. It silently fails (no Apache logs on my server) and even debugging locally I get zero log output or errors of any kind, and I can't get my debugger working in `vscode`. I'm kind of stuck without any ideas. My server-side upload is below; any ideas?

````
$ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
$storeFolder = 'uploads/monthly_product_images';
$imageName = $this->nativesession->get("userId") . "-" . time() . "-" . $_FILES['productImage']['name'];

    if (empty($_FILES)) {
        throw new Exception("Files array is empty!");
    }

$tempFile = $_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'];     
$targetPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds; 
$targetFile =  $targetPath . $imageName; 
log_message('debug', "targetFile value: " . $targetFile);

move_uploaded_file($tempFile, $targetFile);
echo $storeFolder . "/" . $imageName;```
````